# Change decimal number(dynamically changed) style to roman or katakana in some html tag (or div, class, id etc.) using html+css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Searched everywhere but found only [list styling](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_ol_type_all_css) guides and [counter styling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@counter-style) guides in css that didn't worked out.
So I have for e.g. `<html-tag class="class" id="id">23</html-tag>` number inside html-tag is changed dynamically(counter) using vue watch. I want to display number in upper roman or katakana (basically any known formats that supported by modern browsers)
The preferred answer is simple html+css or short js implementation

Answer (score 1):

You need [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat)

For example

```
// the nu extension key requests a numbering system, e.g. Chinese decimal
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('zh-Hans-CN-u-nu-hanidec').format(number));
// → 一二三,四五六.七八九
```

Answer (score 1):

For Roman Numerals 1-99 you could use a function like this:

```js
function convertToRoman(num) {
  const units = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII', 'VIII', 'IX'];
  const tens = ['X', 'XX', 'XXX', 'XL', 'L', 'LX', 'LXX', 'LXXX', 'XC'];
  let numArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
    numArr.push(i);
  }

  const roman = numArr.map(i => {
    if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0) return tens[(i + 1) / 10 - 1];
    else if (i < 10) return units[i];
    else return `${tens[Math.floor(i / 10) - 1]}${units[i.toString().split("")[1]]}`;
  });
  
  return roman[num - 1];
}

console.log(convertToRoman(23))
```